# How do IDEs get the project file list from cmake CMakeList.txt? (and why are LLVMs headers not visible?)

Tags: cmake, qt-creator, llvm

If I build LLVM with QtCreator using CMake, the header files do not show up in the Project window.

Steps to reproduce:

1. `$ git clone http://llvm.org/git/llvm.git`
2. Open QtCreator
3. Open File or Project...
4. Select `llvm/CMakeLists.txt`
5. Build
6. Go to Project window
7. Twiddle open `include/llvm`

Expected Behaviour:  Show header files

Observed Behaviour: No header files

I think I've noticed this in other IDEs as well.  The IDE must be infering from the CMakeList.txt what files are interesting to show up in the Project window, and for some reason the header files are not considered.

My question is, how does QtCreator (or other IDEs) form the list of files it shows in the Project window from CMakeLists.txt, and what is it about the LLVM CMakeList.txt files that mean that header files do not show up?

Comment: In CMake when I add a target I always add the headers to the target as well as the source files. If you do not add the headers they will not show up as part of the project in several IDEs or at least this is what I do in Visual Studio.

Comment: @drescherjm: How do you add headers to a target?

Comment: In the CMakeLists.txt that I create for my projects I include the headers in `ADD_EXECUTABLE(my_exe ${MYEXE_SOURCE_FILES} ${MYEXE_HEADERS})` or `add_library(my_library ${MYLIB_SOURCE_FILES} ${MYLIB_HEADERS})` .